# While loop keeps on running after condition is met

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator using Python.

I want the user to write "and", and then the while loop should end. When I run it and type in random text, the while loop works and says "try again". However, when I actually input the correct answer ("add"), the while loop doesn't end- instead, it keeps on saying "try again".

Why is this happening? Whats wrong with my code?

```py
input('Welcome! This is a calculator app that allows you to perform basic arithmetic operations with whole and decimal numbers. Press Enter to continue.')

operation = input('Please pick one of the following operations: Multiply, Add, Divide or Subtract ')

while True:
    if operation != 'add':
        input('Please try again: ')
    else:
        print('All good')
        break
```

Comment: please format your code in the code block, by highlighting it and clicking the {} button

Comment: `while` loop won't break since you are not storing new input in `operation` variable

Comment: Check out a [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/calculator) to learn about variables and inputs

Comment: The loop needs to be able to read the values that are being inputted.

Comment: You are not re-assigning the try again input to `operation` inside the loop. Moreover you can simplify the conditions: `while operation != 'add':`, dropping the `if` and printing all good after that loop.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so look here:

```
if operation != 'add':
    input('Please try again:')
```

This code only allows user to input something, but where?
We need to input into the operation value.

```
if operation != 'add':
    operation = input('Please try again:')
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more on that. Like why i needed to assign the try again input to operation.

Comment: Because you are using the operation in the if statement, so if you don't input into operation and give it a new value, the operation value will remain what it is you first input into it.